# Triggering change event still use the old event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i load the page, change event handler is triggered. The original change event handler is called instead of new handler, after the page is loaded, it uses correct handler. How can i make it use the new handler on triggering?

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
<ul>
    <li>S1
        <select class="b1">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>S2
        <select class="b1">
            <option>White</option>
            <option>Blue</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').each(function () {

        <!----- Original code, can not be modified ----->

        var doc = this;
        $(doc).on('change', '.b1', function(ev){
            alert('this should not run');
        });

        $('ul', doc).each(function () {
            $('.b1', this).first().trigger('change');
        });
        <!------------- END -------------->

        <!----- Override change event ----->

        $(doc).off('change', '.b1');
        $(doc).on('change', '.b1', function(ev){
            alert('new change handler');
        }); 

        <!------------- END -------------->
    });
});
```

Comment: First off, `body.each` is wrong as a valid `html` document can only have 1 `body` tag. Are you allowed to add some code before the one in your post?

Comment: @LShetty well, my mistake instead of body it should be a div

Comment: Right, edit your question then and answer my other question as well.

Comment: @LShetty i can not edit code in original section and the override section is in another file

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs sequentially - the code that you can't modify is triggering the change event on the element (via `$('.b1', this).first().trigger('change');`) before you have the opportunity to remove the event handler.

Comment: is their any way i can prevent it from running?

Comment: @sajadkk if you're able to modify the HTML, you could remove the `b1` classes, then add them in your JavaScript after the code that can't be modified.